# Search function Hit service when difference between two letter exceeds 3 secs

Tags: angular, timer

My search function works properly but it hits the service for each letter typed. So, I want to hit the service when there is a gap between two input letter exceeds 3sec.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Please post your code here, so people can see how far you've gone and try to help. You should narrow your options. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

First define in your component:

```
var search$: Subject<string> = new BehavioralSubject<string>('');
```

next when the search was update do:

```
searchUpdated(value: string){
  this.search$.next(value);
}
```

Then add in your `ngInit`

```
this.search$.debounce(3000).subscribe(searchTerm => this.searchService.update(searchTerm));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.search(term: string)
.debounce(3000)               
.filter(term => term.length > 2 )
.subscribe();
```

You can see this for ref.
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: If I use `dobounce` I am getting error in service response

Answer (score 0):

```
GetSearchResult(searchKey:any)
    {
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => { 
           this.service.GetSearchItems(searchKey)
           .subscribe(
               response =>{
               this.TableResponse = response;
           }); 
       }, 3000);
    }

clearTimer()
{ 
   if(this.timer != null)
   clearTimeout(this.timer);
}
```

OnChange I will `setTimeOut` for service call and when the key pressed before the timeout `keydown` event triggered and `clearTimeOut`